# Spring Integration: how to open the circuit-breaker of a service based on the state of another service?

Tags: spring-integration

I have a flow like the one that follows in an application using Spring Integration 4.0.4:

```
Inbound --A--> Service 1 --B--> Service 2 --C--> Service 3 --D--> End service 4
```

*Service 3* might fail regularly (this is expected). I am using a `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice` on *Service 3* to take care of this failure, and to retry after a while. However, I need to stop *Service 2* from processing the messages it receives from **channel B** if *Service 3* circuit-breaker is opened (some context: *Service 3* imports files put in an Amazon S3 bucket by *Service 2*. If *Service 3* is down, there is no point in uploading the files, since this operation is not free).

So far, I have some ideas: I would subclass `AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice` in a similar fashion to what is achieved by `RequestHandlerCircuitBreakerAdvice`, and then use a slightly modified version of `doInvoke()` to check not only the state of the current service (*Service 2*), but also the state of *Service 3*, and then open the circuit-breaker of *Service 2* as well if *Service 3* is in failed state. However, how can I identify which service calls the `doInvoke()` method? The differentiation is made on the `target` argument (as this is the thing stored in the state Map) but it is received as an `Object`.

This `target` can be cast to `AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.RequestHandler` but this does not help much to identify the service.

## Question

How can I identify which service is being checked in the `doInvoke()` method? Is there any other way to implement such a "synced-circuit-breaker" feature? I was thinking about having in the message headers a specific flag when a message is sent to *Service 3*, so that I know that `target` is actually *Service 3*... but any input on a cleverer solution would be highly appreciated!

## Additional info

I tried to implement the answer of Gary as follow:

```
<!-- Service bean definition -->
<bean id="service3Bean" class="com.me.Service3"/>

<!-- Circuit breaker advice -->
<bean id="circuitBreaker" class="com.me.Service3StateBasedCircuitBreaker">
    <property name="threshold" value="10" />
    <property name="halfOpenAfter" value="60000" />
    <property name="service3" ref="service3.handler" />
</bean> 

<int:chain input-channel="channelC" output-channel="channelD">
    <int:header-enricher>
        (...)
    </int:header-enricher>
        
    <!-- Transformer implementing Service 3 definition -->
    <int:transformer id="service3" ref="service3Bean" method="doSomething">
        <int:request-handler-advice-chain>
            <ref bean="circuitBreaker" />
        </int:request-handler-advice-chain>
    </int:transformer>
</int:chain>
```

This gives me a `No bean named 'service3.handler' is defined` error at runtime. Maybe a precedence problem, but I cannot spot it. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A subclass would work - apply the same advice instance to both services (so they share the state `Map`).

Inject the service3's handler into your advice (`<property name="service3" ref="service3.handler" />`) -  handlers get an alias of `beanName.handler`.

Then in the logic, as well as testing the state of target, you can also check the state of service3 (or just test service3).

If you do this in a generic way (e.g. allow injecting a `Collection` of other service handlers to examine), we would be happy to consider adding this capability to the framework.

See the [contributing guidelines](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-integration/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md).

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I get the idea, but when trying to pass my service as property to my advice: `No bean named 'service3.handler' is defined`. Service 3 is well defined and working, being a bean used as `ref` for a `<int:transformer>`. I tried many different combinations (defining `id` on the transformer, inline bean definition in the transformer of the service bean, etc.) without any luck. Did I miss something obvious?

Comment: Can you show your actual configuration? If the transformer has an ID "foo", the handler should exist under an alias "foo.handler". (Edit your question rather than pasting into a comment).

Comment: Ah, your service is within a `<chain/>`; in that case, give the chain an `id` and the handler is now `chainId$child.service3.handler`. This is discussed in [Configuring a Chain](http://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-routing-chapter.html#chain-namespace).